R Markdown, Knit
I'm having a problem with my R Markdown file being executed for the knit feature (IDK all the right lingo so forgive me if this is confusing). Instead of the Desktop version of R Studio, I'm using the cloud version. I'm trying to publish the knit version of my R markdown file and it doesn't go through all the way. I'm trying to figure out what the problem is. I keep getting this message:
Quitting from lines  at lines 39-45 [unnamed-chunk-1] (Bella-Beat-Report.Rmd)
Error in .External2():
! unable to start data viewer
Backtrace:

utils::View(dailyActivity_merged)
Execution halted

Thank you.
After putting in all my code, I hit the knit button at the top of the window. Apparently, that's all I need but it won't convert my files code chunks to any type of file (HTML, PDF or Word).

Comment or Remove the code line View(dailyActivity_merged).

Thank you. Can you explain why it does that?

You have a call to View(dailyActivity_merged) in that code chunk.  View() tries to open an interactive viewer of the dataset, but you're trying to produce a static document.  Apparently it isn't prepared to give you a static view, so it fails.
Some alternatives are to just print that dataset, or perhaps call knitr::kable() on it to produce a formatted table.  If it's a really big dataset, neither of those is good; they don't produce a scrolling display, they try to show the whole thing.
